# Update Profile During SignUp Angular Firebase

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire

I am using angularfire/firebase for an Angular project where I am working through authentication.

When a user signs up, the following function is called:

```
  signup(email: string, password: string, name: string) {
    return this.fireAuth
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((res) => {
        res.user?.updateProfile({
          displayName: name,
        });

        // set vars and local storage
      });
  }
```

In my `app.component`, I have the following subscription to track changes and store in my state management (I don't think StateMgmt is the issue here):

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.fireAuth.authState.user.subscribe((res) => {
  if(res) {
    console.log(res);
    console.log(res.displayName);
    this.store.dispatch(new SetUser(res));
  }
}
```

When a user signs up, the name they enter upon signup is set through the `res.user.updateProfile(...` function, and since the authState had a change, the subscription in the app.component prints out an object and stores to the `SetUser(res)` state.

The `console.log()` from here in the app state prints out a large object, *including* the `email`,  `uid`, and `displayName`. This is then stored in my state object. However, on the`console.log(res.displayName)`, the result is null until I refresh the page triggering an "auto logon" where the displayName is fetched from firebase.

It seems to me the object of the `.then((res)...` from my `signUp()` updateProfile is not being triggered until after the user is already changed and stored.

Is there a way to make this signUp function work so that the `SetUser(res)` is only dispatched once the `updateProfile({...` is complete and the displayName is no longer null?

From my `app.component` `console.log(res)`:

```
{
 "uid": "vbn6TA8vTiLi7J2",
 "displayName": "my name",
 "photoURL": null,
 "email": "email@email.com",
 ...
}
```

`app.component` `console.log(res.displayName)`:
`null`

##### EDIT

Another interesting thing I found is that when I take a copy of the `res` and print it out, the displayName is also null.

```
 const r = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res));
 console.log(res);
 console.log(r);
```

the `console.log(r)` has an object where the `displayName` is null. The `console.log(res)` has an object where the `displayName` is NOT null and is the name passed in to the `signUp(...` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even waiting for the user to be finalized via async await before moving on did not work.

What I ended up doing was the following:

In my `signUp()` function, once the user was created, I retrieved the current use via `this.fireAuth.authState` (fireAuth is from `AngularFireAuth` in my constructor). I subscribed to this, while piping to only take the first value, and then dispatched my `SetUser` function. This ensures that the function is only running after the `updateProfile` is complete using a `.then()`.

Because I moved the state dispatch into my signup function, I removed the subscription from my AppComponent.

Here is my signup function from the auth service:

```
...

  constructor(
    public fireAuth: AngularFireAuth,
  ) {
    this.user = this.fireAuth.authState;
  }

  signup(email: string, password: string, name: string) {
    return this.fireAuth
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((res) => {
        res.user
          ?.updateProfile({
            displayName: name,
          })
          .then(() => {
            this.user.pipe(first()).subscribe((res) => {
              this.store.dispatch(new SetUser(res));
            });
          });
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This maybe a race condition within Angular Fire, I would ensure that the user is finalized before updating the user.

```js
async UpdateProfile(displayName: string) {
    const profile = {
       displayName: stored.username,
       photoURL: stored.profile,
       email: stored.email,
    }
    return (await this.afAuth.currentUser).updateProfile(profile);
}
```

I am making the assumption you are storing the user details via a form object as `stored` but this can easily be from the auth provider or a custom object